# macOS SwiftUI Textfield gets deleted after losing focus

Tags: macos, swiftui, textfield, combine

I have a strange issue where the textfield gets deleted after selecting another textfield.

I have an `EnvironmentObject`

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Create the SwiftUI view that provides the window contents.
        let shellInteractor = ShellInteractor()
        let contentView = ContentView().environmentObject(shellInteractor)
}
```

injected in the view

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var shellInteractor: ShellInteractor

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Text("Enter target bundle identifier:")
                    TextField("com.mycompany.app", text: $shellInteractor.bundleId)
                }.padding()
                HStack {
                    Text("Enter icon badge count:")
                    TextField("0", text: $shellInteractor.badgeNumber)
                }.padding()
                HStack {
                    Text("Enter message identifier:")
                    TextField("ABCDEFGHIJ", text: $shellInteractor.messageId)
                }.padding()

                Text("Found Running Sim: ")
                Text(self.shellInteractor.shellOutput).fontWeight(.semibold)
                Button(action: {
                    self.shellInteractor.sendNotification()
                }) {
                    Text("SEND!!!")
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                }.padding()
            }.padding()
        }
    }
}
```

```
class ShellInteractor: ObservableObject {
    @Published var shellOutput: String = ""

    public var badgeNumber: String = ""
    public var messageId: String = ""
    public var bundleId: String = ""
}
```

As I said, when I enter a text in any of the textfields and select another text field or tap the `TAB` key (basically when losing focus), the textfield deletes the text and shows the placeholder again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update your model

```
class ShellInteractor: ObservableObject {
    @Published var shellOutput: String = ""

    @Published var badgeNumber: String = ""
    @Published var messageId: String = ""
    @Published var bundleId: String = ""
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was it!

Comment: @AlexBartiş unfortunately, such a things have to be recognized by compiler.by the way is kind of workaround, your code works as written on iOS

Comment: Yeah, it makes sense.